# C# CLI RPG: Why I can't console log my List(Inventory) of type Struct(InventoryItem)?

Tags: c#, list, struct

**Desired Behavior:**

I did read somewhere that structs in C# are hard, however in Game Engines, I always did my inventory with list of struct type. Basically Inventory needs to keep items in it that have different variables (defence, attack, etc) - perfect for structs.

.

**What's Not Working:**

After I create Struct type, list of this type, and add item to it, I can't display it with any form of ForEach loop I tried. It displays **CLI_RPG.InventoryItem** instead, where CLI_RPG is name of project, and InventoryItem is struct type.

.

**What I think could be wrong:**

I think I made file/class with Struct in a wrong way. It doesn't give errors, though.

.

**Program Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CLI_RPG
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Character character = new Character();
            character.ShowStatistics();

            //Create List Of Struct Type
            List<InventoryItem> Inventory = new List<InventoryItem>();
            InventoryItem WoodenSword = new InventoryItem("Wooden Sword", 25, 7, 0, 50, 10);
            Inventory.Add(WoodenSword);

            // Show Struct Elements
            Inventory.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

.

**Struct Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CLI_RPG
{
    public struct InventoryItem
    {
        public string name;

        public int durability;

        public int damage;
        public int defence;

        public int buyPrice;
        public int sellPrice;

        public InventoryItem(string name, int durability, int damage, int defence, int buyPrice, int sellPrice)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.durability = durability;
            this.damage = damage;
            this.defence = defence;
            this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
            this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

.

Any help appreciated! I have to learn and understand these before I start making games!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct , your struct does not qualify for "It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.)." "It has an instance size under 16 bytes."...

Comment: I checked size and decreased it to 8 bytes. What do you mean "it logically represents a single value"?

Comment: nvm got it working, i was displaying the value wrongly.

Comment: This is not a document I wrote, it's Microsoft's recommendations. Why did you opt for a struct?

Comment: @vc74 i didnt know how to make a class inventory, but i found the way afterwards